# Coda 2: How to enable Auto Closing Tag support

Tags: autocomplete, tags, coda

I am using CODA 2 for mac and I want the editor to complete my closing Tag!

example:

I am typing:

```
<div>
```

I want the editor to autocomplete the

```
</div>
```

tag

I have already checked the plugin store of coda: https://panic.com/coda/plugins.php

but without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a editor as visual studio code or sublime text. Every editor doesn't contain the support for auto closing tags

Answer (score 0):

just type `</`

Its not a plugin as such but this is how you complete tags in Coda2.